# Common input and output statements

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In my application, I have two buttons. I am taking an input and based on which button is clicked, displaying an output. However, for this, I have to write input and output statements in each of the button's OnClickListener(). This is making the code bulky. Is there any way by which I can write common input and output statements.

My current code looks something like this.

```
Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        input();
        process1();
        output();
    }
});

Button2.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg1) {
        input();
        process2();
        output();
    }
});
```

I want my code to be something like this:

```
input();
Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        process1();
    }
});

Button2.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg1) {
        process2();
    }
});
output();
```

Is this possible ? If yes then how ? If no then why ?

Thank You !

**Edit:**

input() is: `input = Double.parseDouble(inputString.getText().toString());`

output() is: `outputString.setText(String.valueOf(output));`

`input` and `output` are `double` and defined already.

output is calculated from input by simple arithmetic `process1()` and `process2()`.

`inputString` is `EditText` and `outputString` is `TextView`.

Comment: We would need some idea about what do input and output methods do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's worth the trouble, but you could create an abstract class `BaseListener` that implements `OnClickListener`. Its `onClick` method would look like this :

```
public void onClick(View arg1) 
{
    input();
    process();
    output();
}
```

`process()` would be an abstract method.

Each Button would have a listener that extends `BaseListener` and implements `process()`.

For example :

```
Button1.setOnClickListener(new BaseListener () {
    protected void process() {
        process1();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the way to go. Its a Design Pattern called a "Template Method".

Comment: The input method cannot look like that because it is obviously an Activity method. But yeah this is the way to go in general.

Answer (score 0):

Is not the best way, but you can extract a method:

```
void process(int btn) {
   input();
   if(btn == 1) process1();
   else if (btn == 2) process2();
   output();
}
```

And call it this way:

```
Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
      process(1);
   }
});

Button2.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg1) {
      process(2);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways...on way is like this.

```
Button1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
Button2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        input();
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            process1();
            output();
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            process2();
            break;

        }
        output();
    }
};
```